# Use local dependecy on AWS CodeBuild for Angular Project

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-codebuild

I have a build project on CodeBuild, problem is one of the dependencies of the project is located on the build machine, for example mine.

The package.json part where the dependency is:

`"company-kit": "file:../../company-kit/releases",`

When we try to build the log return is this:

```
'source error TS2307: Cannot find module' 'company-kit'.
'source error TS2307: Cannot find module' 'company-kit'.
'source error TS2307: Cannot find module' 'company-kit'.
```

(Some values were changed to hide possible sensitive information)

The buildspec.yml is currently like this:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
    pre_build:
        commands:
            - npm install
    build:
        commands:
            - npm run build-prod
```

How can I make it so the CodeBuild find the needed package?

Answer (score 0):

you can publish dependency Package in code artifacts with creation all your NPM repository. and before install the packages login to code artifacts with npm repository.

when you run npm install, it will download the dependency from code artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

After researching, I found a way by:

1. Navigate to where the build should be, in my case at ../../company-kit/releases
2. Cloning the repo with the dependency from AWS Codecommit
3. Building it
4. Navigating back to the original folder with my source
5. Finish the buildspec

However I couldn't complete the build because of another errors about some modules, but the solution above helped me at leaset get past the dependency part